# Cannot post question from Google Chrome "because the form's frame is sandboxed"

Tags: bug, google-chrome

When trying to post a question to Stack Overflow from Chrome 55.0.2883.87, I get the following error message:

> Blocked form submission to '/questions/ask/submit' because the form's frame is sandboxed and the 'allow-forms' permission is not set.

Comment: Does this also happen when you access the site over HTTPS?

Comment: Yes, https also

Comment: Reading [the SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24531061/blocked-script-execution-in-because-the-documents-frame-is-sandboxed-angular) here, it seems there are `iframe`s that's blocking this. However, I couldn't find any `iframe` when looking on the source. Are you using any extensions? Worst case, probably there's malware injecting the `iframe` to the page... **EDIT**: apparently the error message is slightly different, not sure if this is the case.

Comment: No 'frame' in Elements tab found. Without any extension nothing changes.

Comment: Succefully posted from incognito mode, so I wont be able to test this some time...

Comment: Pretty sure there is an plugin in your browser that plays tricks on you, specially if the problems disappear when you use incognito mode.

Comment: Same (just default) chrome://plugins/ in incognito mode.

Comment: @user3009578 You need to look in `chrome://extensions/` too.

Comment: @user3009578: *"No 'frame' in Elements tab found."* `frame` and `iframe` are not the same thing. But yes, this is clearly caused by an extension.

Comment: It's also possible that you navigated to SO from a sandboxed iframe. In that case the sandbox gets copied over to the new window.

Comment: @cybermonkey of course when I say "Without any extension" I disabled all of them.

Comment: @MatthijsWessels open favorites

Comment: can you post a screenshot of the dev tools' elements tab when you open stackoverflow?

Comment: @DanielA.White Sorry, blue button is pressable again.